# How do I fix jQuery's toggle function when not toggling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a menu that I want to toggle once the user clicks on the user's icon but right now it isn't working and I don't know why. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me fix it. My code right now is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready({
        $('.account-icon').click(function({
            $('.MenujQuery').toggle('slow');
        }))
    });
</script>

<div id="user-menu">
    <img class="account-icon" src="/img/logicon.png" alt="Your Profile">
    <ul class="MenujQuery" style="display: none">
        <li class="user-item"><a href="/index.php?action=profile">Update profile</a></li>
        <li class="user-item"><a href="/index.php?action=purchases">My purchases</a></li>
        <li class="user-item"><a href="/index.php?action=logout">Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole jQuery code is syntactically nonsense. Here is how it should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.account-icon').click(function() {
        $('.MenujQuery').toggle('slow');
    })
});
```

It looks like you hand-copied the code from somewhere else without really understanding what it is doing, and incidentally messed up the syntax. I suggest doing some tutorials first.